# How do I print time stamp in git bash after executing each git command?

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell, terminal

```
$ git pull origin develop
21/04/2016 20:15:33
```

I want something like this to be printed to know when i executed the command.

Comment: `$PROMPT_COMMAND` might be useful.

Comment: `git pull origin develop && date`.

Comment: Or maybe something like `git() { command git "$@"; date; }` ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1023492/how-can-i-configure-git-bash-to-display-a-timestamp-for-each-command

Answer (score 4):

You can define an alias in your `~/.bashrc` file, something like this:

`alias git='date && git'`

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add a timestamp to your bash prompt. You do this by setting the `PS1` or `PS2` environment variable for your shell. Read https://askubuntu.com/questions/193416/adding-timestamps-to-terminal-prompts for more details about how to do this.